# Is this grammatically correct - "The fibre in cereal help us feel fuller"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

There's a disagreement going down on this [subreddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/australia/comments/tzm27v/am_i_crazy_shouldnt_this_say_helps/i41jcgv) as to whether the sentence is grammatically correct. It's taken from a cereal ad:

The argument is:

> "The fibre in Sultana Bran help us feel fuller"

is grammatically incorrect and should be

> "The fibre in Sultana Bran helps us feel fuller"

Fibre is referring to an abstract amount of multiple or uncountable fibres, so it's fine to refer to it as just *fibre*. Assuming this, we can say:

> "They help us feel fuller"

This sounds correct and is what the original sentence follows. If we follow the argument people are making, it doesn't make sense

> "They helps us"

Am I wrong here?

Comment: "helps us" is correct.

Comment: But using ‘they’ to refer to fiber is not.  ***It*** helps us feel fuller.

Comment: We speak of _fibres_ in the textile sense, but as a constituent of food it's an uncountable noun.